# if inside class attribute html

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

Navigation

```
    <li>
      <a href="<?=base_url();?>backend/Administrator"
        class="<?php ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? 'class="waves-effect active"' : 'class="waves-effect"'; ?>"><i class="zmdi zmdi-view-dashboard"></i> <span> Home </span> </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="<?=base_url();?>backend/Item" class="waves-effect"><i class="zmdi zmdi-view-list-alt"></i> <span> Item Management </span> </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="<?=base_url();?>backend/Item/tag" class="waves-effect"><i class="zmdi zmdi-collection-plus"></i> <span> Category Management </span> </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="<?=base_url();?>backend/User" class="waves-effect"><i class="zmdi zmdi-account-o"></i> <span> User Management </span> </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="<?=base_url();?>backend/Transaksi" class="waves-effect"><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i> <span> Transactions </span> </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="<?=base_url();?>backend/Transaksi/report" class="waves-effect"><i class="zmdi zmdi-comment-more"></i> <span> Report </span> </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

I'm using if inside the class, but it's not working.

If the URL is active then use class `waves-effect active`. If inactive then use class `waves-effect`

 Please help me with any solution.

Comment: put `echo` before the output

Answer (score 1):

Because the class attribute is repeated and some echos are missing.

Replace:

```
class="<?php ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? 'class="waves-effect active"' : 'class="waves-effect"'; ?>"
```

With:

```
class="<?php ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ? echo 'waves-effect active' : echo 'waves-effect') ?>"
```

Or:

```
<?php ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ? echo 'class="waves-effect active"' : echo 'class="waves-effect"') ?>
```

There is more than one possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

you need to `echo` the values and delete `class=` part if you don't want it will being repeated

```
<li>
  <a href="<?=base_url();?>backend/Administrator"
    class="<?php ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? echo 'waves-effect active' : echo 'waves-effect'; ?>"><i class="zmdi zmdi-view-dashboard"></i> <span> Home </span> </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

With what you have $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] will probably always exist so your test is always going to result in the TRUE value of your ternary.

Are you after something more like

```
<li>
    <a href="<?= base_url(); ?>backend/Administrator"
       class="<?= ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/home/') ? 'waves-effect active' : 'waves-effect'; ?>">
       <i class="zmdi zmdi-view-dashboard"></i> <span> Home </span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Here you are testing for an actual path instead of just testing if it exists.

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/home/'
```

You can just echo the 'string' using `<?=`

```
<?= ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/home/') ? 'waves-effect active' : 'waves-effect'; ?>
```

You should do a **var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);** to see what this global does and to make sure what your paths look like to achieve what you want.

**Messing with '/' slashes can be a pain, so...**
There are a few things you can do, like using trim to clean up the leading/trailing slashes '/' to get out of a potential issue with slashes that could drive you mad.

```
trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/') =='home'
```

**A further simplification for your class would be...**

```
class="waves-effect<?= (trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/') =='home') ? ' active' : ''; ?>">
```

or

```
class="waves-effect <?= (trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/') =='home') ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
```

NOTE Where the Space is between the existing class and the 'added' class definition - active.

You'll need to play with it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You could be using CodeIgniter URI class and URL helper to make things cleaner and easier:

```
<?php

$this->load->helper('url');

$links = [
   [
        'uriStr' => 'backend/administrator',
        'text'   => 'Home',
        'icon'   => 'zmdi zmdi-view-dashboard', 
   ],
   [
        'uriStr' => 'backend/item',
        'text'   => 'Item Management',
        'icon'   => 'zmdi zmdi-view-list-al', 
   ],
   [
        'uriStr' => 'backend/item/tag',
        'text'   => 'Category Management',
        'icon'   => 'zmdi zmdi-collection-plus', 
   ],
   [
        'uriStr' => 'backend/user',
        'text'   => 'User Management',
        'icon'   => 'zmdi zmdi-account-o', 
   ],
   [
        'uriStr' => 'backend/transaksi',
        'text'   => 'Transactions',
        'icon'   => 'fa fa-exchange', 
   ],
   [
        'uriStr' => 'backend/transaksi/report',
        'text'   => 'Report',
        'icon'   => 'zmdi zmdi-comment-more', 
   ],
];

foreach( $links as $link )
{
    $icon = '<i class="' . $link['icon'] . '"></i>';

    $class = $this->uri->uri_string() == $link['uriStr']
        ? 'waves-effect active'
        : 'waves-effect';

    echo '<li>' . 
        anchor( $link['uriStr'], $icon . ' <span> ' . $link['text'] . ' </span> ', 'class="' . $class . '"' ) . 
    '</li>' . 
    PHP_EOL;
}
```